# Pyinstaller does not include geos_c.dll in venv

Tags: python, pyinstaller, shapely

I have a project which uses Shapely and I want to create a single exe file of the project. The geos_c.dll which is included in Shapely does not seem to be included to the exe by Pyinstaller, but only when I'm using virtual environment. How could I get it included using venv?

I'm able reproduce the issue with simple code below.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
print("ok")
```

In my project folder I have set up a virtual environment with the command

```
python -m venv venv
```

Then I activated the venv from the ./venv/Scripts/activate.bat. When activated, I first install Shapely and Pyinstaller with pip, and use Pyinstaller to create the exe with the following code

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

I can see there comes a warning

```
WARNING: lib not found: geos_c.dll dependency of c:\.\venv\lib\site-packages\shapely\speedups\_speedups.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
```

The geos_c.dll is in

```
C:\.\venv\Lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs
```

When I start the created exe via command prompt I get the following error:

```
OSError: Could not find geos_c.dll or load any of its variants
```

Update 2021-12-07

Python version in use is 3.7.9.

Comment: What's the version of Python that you use ?

Comment: Python version update to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the solution for me was to add the .dll files to the .spec file

```
datas=[("yourpath\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\shapely\\DLLs\\geos.dll", ".") ,("yourpath\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\shapely\\DLLs\\geos_c.dll", ".")],
```

then build using the spec file

```
pyinstaller demo.spec
```